# Windows 10 Synaptics Trackpad 3 finger tap opens cortana even after regedit fix

Tags: windows-10, gestures, synaptics-touchpad

I have a synaptics trackpad (fully updated drivers) and I want the three finger tap to act as middle click but at the momment it opens cortana search start menu. I tried a fix where I changed the value of 3FingerTapAction to 4 in regedit. After restarting the finger tap acted as middle click for a few secconds and then reverted to opening cortana. Upon opening regedit I saw that the value is still 4. If anyone can figure out the problem I would be really greatful.

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  This is just a PITA.  I'm able to disable launch of Cortana, but unable to convert a three button tap into a three button click (even with autohotkey).